# How to reset a variable in an infinite generator?

Tags: python, generator

I have an infinite generator object which yields some numbers, like below:

```py
def index_generator():
    i = 0
    while True:
        yield i**2
        i += 1

my_gen = index_generator()

for i in range(100):
    print(next(my_gen))  # outputs 0,1,4,9, ...
```

Now I need to reset variable `i` to zero after some iterations, to use the generator again; let's say 100 more times in my code. I can't repeat `my_gen = index_generator()` every time. So, any solutions?

Comment: maybe try using a while loop/break to not repeat `my_gen = index_generator()`

Comment: Would be good to know *why* you can't just create a new instance. Because that might rule out other ways as well.

Comment: @FishingCode thanx i'll try that soon

Comment: Maybe [`generator.send`](https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-342.html) is of interest?

Comment: You could hack something together using `send`, but that probably isn't necessary here.

Answer (score 6):

One option is to write a class with a `__next__` method, so it can be used as an iterator, and a `reset` method which resets `i`. The `__iter__` method returning `self` is also needed if you aren't just calling `next` manually.

```py
class IndexGenerator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.i = 0

    def __next__(self):
        r = self.i ** 2
        self.i += 1
        return r

    def reset(self):
        self.i = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self
```

Usage example:

```py
>>> g = IndexGenerator()
>>> next(g)
0
>>> next(g)
1
>>> next(g)
4
>>> next(g)
9
>>> g.reset()
>>> next(g)
0
>>> next(g)
1
>>> for x in g:
...     print(x)
...     if x > 10: break
... 
4
9
16
```

Comment: thats it thank U so much. im new here and cant Vote it yet

Answer (score 2):

A way with `send` which allows to (re)set `i` to a desired value:

```
def index_generator():
    i =  0
    while True:
        reset = yield i**2
        if reset is None:
            i += 1
        else:
            i = reset - 1
```

Demo usage:

```
my_gen = index_generator()
print([next(my_gen) for _ in range(5)])

my_gen.send(0)
print([next(my_gen) for _ in range(5)])

my_gen.send(100)
print([next(my_gen) for _ in range(5)])
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16]
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16]
[10000, 10201, 10404, 10609, 10816]
```

A variation that doesn't use the `- 1` trick but instead just yields:

```
def index_generator():
    i =  0
    while True:
        reset = yield i**2
        if reset is None:
            i += 1
        else:
            i = reset
            yield
```

Comment: just Great ! TNQ

Answer (score 1):

Can you do something like this instead?

```py
for i, val in enumerate(index_generator()):
     print(val)
     if i > 1000:
             break
```

for each time you need to use it?

The for loop calls the next method implicitly, so this is a bit shorter, and the generator 'resets' each time.

Comment: Why are you asking a question in an answer?